# Max size iPad / iPhone Offline Application Cache

Tags: iphone, caching, ipad, offline

Anyone knows the max size of Safari's 'Offline Application Cache' on the iPad & iPhone. Looks like it's 5MB. Is there any way to enlarge this size?

Offline application cache docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/OfflineApplicationCache/OfflineApplicationCache.html

Comment: I could bump it to 50 MB without any trouble.

Answer (score 9):

I have the same problem on iPhone. On iPad though I figured a turn around. If your manifest contains files less than 5MB the first time and you update the cache by window.applicationCache.update() and before doing the update you increase the manifest files to be below 10mb it will work. If you continue doing that (increasing the manifest by <5MB each time and then update()) you will see that the iPad can cache more than the 5MB limit.

It is so sad that Apple by not supporting Flash and MIDP but only HTML5 for web-apps screws so much on that.

Answer (score 4):

If your application uses more than 5mb than iPhone/iPad will ask the user to allow the website to use more space.

[image: Increase Local Storage]

Comment: But is there a *max* size?

Comment: @koiyu, I don't know.  We didn't test the limit because we had a very specific amount of data to store.  Our data was 125mb total.

Comment: With iOS 10 clicking on "Increase" on that dialog just crashes Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Let's read my test at here: [Mobile Safari 5mb HTML5 application cache limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908459/mobile-safari-5mb-html5-application-cache-limit/10195265#10195265)

I think your apps need user's agreement for storage more than 5MB. Another problem you get is the network problem. It's too slow for 50MB transferring...