# How can I play video offline on iPad, using an HTML 5 web app (using Sencha touch or otherwise)

Tags: video, ipad, html, manifest, offline

I've created a web app (using Sencha Touch, but that's not important) which I'm trying to get offline. It's a slideshow with images and a video.
When online, it plays an mp4 video using the  tag in HTML .
I can take it offline using a cache manifest file, which works fine for all other content, but my video won't play when offline.

I've used the "add to home screen" button to create a web app icon on the home screen.

Comment: What size is the video? Mobile Safari has a 5mb cache limit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908459/mobile-safari-5mb-html5-application-cache-limit

Answer (score 0):

You can always provide the source of your video as a base64 string instead of as a URL.  That way the video is actually embedded in the document and will play regardless of internet connectivity.

See this example page and view the page source:  http://iandevlin.com/html5/data-uri/video.php