# size of HTML5 offline cache

Tags: html, offline

Is there any way how to save larger amount of files into html5 app cache?I have a site with plenty of images and when I put it into my manifest file, browser says it will exceed the quota..
And on the iPad seems to be the default value set on 5MB..is possible to change it?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mobile Safari 5mb HTML5 application cache limit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908459/mobile-safari-5mb-html5-application-cache-limit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, there isn't a consistent way for developers to go beyond the typical 5 meg limit. 
Some browsers will prompt users to increase the limit, but others won't.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 6 increases the app cache from 5MB to 25MB (in the iOS 6 beta 4 release notes).