# Mobile Safari iOS cache limit - no prompt to increase local storage

Tags: html, ipad, caching, mobile-safari, cache-manifest

I have seen a few articles on this and a couple of stackoverflow questions

[max-size-ipad-iphone-offline-application-cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772908/max-size-ipad-iphone-offline-application-cache) and

[mobile-safari-5mb-html5-application-cache-limit/10195265#10195265](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908459/mobile-safari-5mb-html5-application-cache-limit/10195265#10195265)

Nothing I try will prompt me to increase the 5MB cache limit. I have tried the manifest file idea mentioned in one of the above stack overflow questions but nothing.
Im using SequelSphere, using this method is great because its cross platform. The only problem is, the 5MB limit has stopped me in my tracks.

Has anyone got any ideas at all as to how to make this larger?

Thank you