# Accessing cache in iPad through HTML5, JS or jQuery 

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, caching

I have created an browser-based application with the use of HTML & javascript, where some videos are embedded into it.
Now to access the application even faster, we wish to access the videos from cache(if available) so as to avoid buffering when accessed by the end-user.

Constraints are : app is used mainly on iPhone / iPad through default Safari-browser and javascript/jQuery solution is needed so as to achieve the requirement ASAP. Also the video sizes are upto 22MB.

Is it possible to access such big videos to be managed by cache on iPad, can those be accessed from javascript or jQuery ?

Comment: Possibly what you look for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772908/max-size-ipad-iphone-offline-application-cache

Answer (score 1):

File caches are the browsers responsibility (or servers/applications). You can use Cache-control HTTP headers for some measure of control:
http://condor.depaul.edu/dmumaugh/readings/handouts/SE435/HTTP/node24.html

but in the end it's highly dependent on which browsers you are using. I would suggest looking up top "most used" browsers in iPad and research how their file cacheing works.

An alternative suggestion, perhaps you should use HTML5 "client-side storage"?
http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/html/HTML5-Client-Side/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've edited the question, lets say if end user access more on safari browser on iPad/iPhone do you think its possible to handle videos till 22MB from cache...?

Comment: I just thought of HTML5 local (client-side) storage, perhaps you should research it also.