# What is the maximum cache size for iOS6 web apps and how can I extend it?

Tags: html, ios6, html5-appcache, cache-manifest

I'm building a web app especially for the iPad (running iOS 6+) showing the product collection of a company.

It all worked perfectly using HTML5's "cache.manifest" file. But since the cache has grown to about 50MB the iPad is not saving the application data anymore. Instead of 50MB the cache size is now 0.1KB according to the Safari settings.

So what is the actual limit of Safari's cache for a web app and is there a way to enlarge the maximum amount for the application cache?

Comment: Check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772908/max-size-ipad-iphone-offline-application-cache

Answer (score 12, accepted):

edit 2nd june 2014 :
The maximum cache size on iOS7.1 is 300Mb.

A client asked me this precise question recently, so I investigated.

**As per IOS6** (all my tests have been done on **iOS6.1**), these are two different things :

- a website using a .manifest, accessed with mobile Safari
- a webapp on the home screen, created from the website

A website with a .manifest can use up to 50mb of cache, with an user permission asked. It can't use more. This value can be found and cleared in settings/safari/advanced. If you try to stuff more in the cache, a `error` event will be fire and the `window.applicationCache.status` will go IDLE.

**A webapp does not share the same cache than its website.** Clearing the cache settings/safari/advanced won't do anything for you home screen webapp. It will accept more than 50mb of cache without user input, but I don't know exactly how much (I tested with 60mb with success, totally accessible offline. *edit : tried with 83mb, success)
I don't know where this data can be seen in iOS settings. I guess nowhere.

Testing this was a pain in the *** until I found the [spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html). There's an API that works perfectly on iOS6.
You should check `window.applicationCache.status`, which tells you what's the app state, and the following events (cut and paste from my code, so with their listener) :

```
window.applicationCache.addEventListener('checking', onChecking);
window.applicationCache.addEventListener('noupdate', onNoupdate);
window.applicationCache.addEventListener('downloading', onDownloading);
window.applicationCache.addEventListener('progress', onProgress);
window.applicationCache.addEventListener('cached', onCached);
window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', onUpdateready);    
window.applicationCache.addEventListener('obsolete', onObsolete);
window.applicationCache.addEventListener('error', onError);
```

All are working on iOS 6.1, even the `progress` event with `event.loaded` and `event.total`

A webapp starts by checking, then fires `noupdate` if the .manifest is the same. Status is `IDLE`.

If the .manifest changed, status is `DOWNLOADING`, the `progress` event fires for each file in your manifest, then status is `UPDATEREADY` and the `updateready` fires.

If you're offline, an `error` event fires and status is `IDLE`.

You can test the online/offline status with

```
var online = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';
```

It works but the specs says it's unreliable.

Three more things to finish :

- my manifest is named cache.manifest and declared like this `<html manifest="cache.manifest">`
- my .htaccess has `AddType text/cache-manifest manifest` and `ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"`
- my app has `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`

With this API, it's way easier to understand what's going on under the hood. Be sure to do your own test though, I'm not 100% sure of this results or they can could with a new iOS version. I'll test further for the maximum size.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! I'm going to try it out later today or tomorrow.

Comment: It seems that the web application (when it's in the home screen) is only caching on the second time. The first time the error event fired, the second time the cached event fired successfully! Thanks for your help.