# ios cache limit for ipad and iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, caching, limit

I am doing some site scans for some of our apps at work, and one of the issues (from Sort Site)says:

"Images, scripts and CSS files larger than 25k are not cached on iPhone and iPad."

Is this still true? If not, what is the cache limit, if there is one?

Comment: http://www.phpied.com/iphone-caching/, [this](https://www.google.com.kw/search?q=Images%2C+scripts+and+CSS+files+larger+than+25k+are+not+cached+on+iPhone+and+iPad&rlz=1C5CHFA_enKW503KW503&oq=Images%2C+scripts+and+CSS+files+larger+than+25k+are+not+cached+on+iPhone+and+iPad&aqs=chrome.0.69i57.355j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Max size iPad / iPhone Offline Application Cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772908/max-size-ipad-iphone-offline-application-cache)

Comment: The dates on your links Fahim are from 2009. The previous question posted by Marcus Adams does not have an accepted answer. I googled it, and could not find anything current. As I am not an iOS dev, I thought maybe someone would know. A direct answer would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It differs depending on your device iPhone vs iPad and Mobile Safari version. [This](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/06/28/mobile-browser-cache-limits/) study shows that the 25k Page Cache Size Limit apples to Mobile Safari iOS 3.2 on a iPad. But Mobile Safari, iOS 4.0 on a iPhone does not have this limit.

Comment: That was written in 2008, and updated in 2010. Is there a MAC resource with current specs on this info?

Comment: You are right that it pretty old, but I'm assuming newer versions of Mobile Safari wouldn't revert back to older limits. If I find a newer study I'll share with you.

Comment: Other thing you should know is that max persistent cache size remains 0. Even on IOS 6.

Comment: I just tested with a CSS file with a size of 3 Mb on iOS 7, and it caches it, and never reloads it, unless i click the "refresh" button in Safari. So I guess the 25k is kind of a myth, since the recommendation is found in high ranking documents, from 2008, and regards iOS 3. Minification is always good though.

Answer (score 0):

As I read [that 2010 study](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2010/07/12/mobile-browser-cache-limits-revisited/) the 25k limit only applies to your HTML. 
"Try to **limit HTML pages to 25.6KB** or less if you want them to be cached."

Other resources have a much higher limit.  4mb on IOS and 2 MB on Android. I would assume these limits will only increase in future so this study, while dated, is at least a good baseline.